# Configure Bonjour for a custom vhost on Apache on OS X

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost, bonjour

Bonjour is a lovely technology. I would like all my custom vhosts on my mac (Snow Leopard) to broadcast via bonjour. What is the best way to do this, without having to enable for every vhost separately?

Comment: Bonjour is lovely - seriously????  It's the first thing I disable on our Macs...

Comment: Would you care elaborate? I find bonjour amazing. Why do you disable it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be making the assumption you're using the built-in Apache Server, so...

If you open up your `httpd.conf` you can usually see at the very bottom:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
```

The "other" directory contains both php.conf and bonjour.conf

Bonjour.conf has a few oddities though, for one, the default file does not include some of the possible options.
As far as I know there are only three possible options:

---

```
RegisterDefaultSite
```

This broadcasts the main site, not a VHost, and uses the machine's name (As defined by "Computer Name" in the sharing prefs) as the Bojour service title.

---

```
RegisterUserSite
```

this takes one of three options:

```
<a username>
all-users
customized_users
```

The first two are self explanatory, but `customized_users` is rather clever; it checks if each user has made changes to the index.html in `~/Sites`; if so, that user's page is broadcasted.

---

```
RegisterResource
```

This is probably the one you are looking for; it accepts two arguments, a service name and a path.

Ex:

```
RegisterResource HelloLan /
```

---

### My suggestion:

I would try placing a RegisterResource in each VHost, although I don't use VHosts and so I haven't tried it myself.

I have heard the the `mod_bonjour` that is shipped by default has some issues with multiple `RegisterResource` options see here: http://deeperdesign.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/apples-mod_bonjour-is-broken-in-snow-leopard-so-i-fixed-it/.

Someone leaving a comment on the aforementioned page seemed to suggest VHost Bonjour is possible.

so best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you want to register alternative A/CNAME records (eg: devsite1.local, devsite2.local, ...) for your machine so that other machines can access the virtual hosts you've created? There's no easy way to do this as the Bonjour API (unlike Avahi) doesn't allow arbitrary record names to be registered.

Answer (score 0):

On debian i did:
`a2enmod mod-dnssd`
`cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod-dnssd.conf`

```
 # This is the config file for mod_dnssd.<br>
< IfModule mod_dnssd.c><br>
    DNSSDEnable On<br>
< /IfModule>
```

this applies to all vhosts at once.