# Configure Bonjour for a custom vhost on Apache on OS X 10.9

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost, bonjour

How to broadcast all my vhost ?  [This has been answered for Snow Leopard](https://serverfault.com/questions/104326/configure-bonjour-for-a-custom-vhost-on-apache-on-os-x), sadly the configurations files pointed in this thread are not there anymore in Maverick.